# What is the appropriate site to ask questions regarding improvements to human society?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

What is the appropriate Stack Exchange website to ask questions regarding possible improvements to human civilization and society? Questions like "What is the best possible government?" or "What is the best language to speak?" or "Should the calendar be based on the birth of someone who lived 2000 years ago?", etc.

Comment: Example question? Your description may be clear to you but you know what you're talking about. Please flesh out your question to help us direct you more accurately.

Comment: "What is the best..." questions generally aren't well suited to the SE network. Most sites require objective questions.

Comment: Maybe worldbuilding.se take those kind of questions.

Comment: @rene I haven't posted there, but a look through their help center indicates it wouldn't be on topic.  They specifically call out  that it's important that the questions not be opinion based, which these very much are.   Specifically, " If you are looking for discussion, brainstorming, or an overall process rather than specific questions and answers, the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange might not be a good place for your question." seems relevant here.

Comment: Yeah, opinion based stuff will not fly anywhere, that is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is with it, that these questions are considered too subjective on the SE. Everybody has more or less concept, what is the best society, but typically we want to see only the opinions similar to ours.

In most cases, you can get an answer for such questions, but you have to ask them on an SE-conform way. There are multiple possibilities to make a question non-opinionated, while you get your answer also for the opinionated question.

The important thing is to separate your *opinion* from your *research*.

You are searching not for the best society, you are searching for something which is the best society *for you*.

For that, there is already a broad spectrum of questions what you already can ask.

1. You can ask about social phylosophy on the Phylosophy SE.
2. You can ask about your home ideas and its possible results on the Worldbuilding SE.
3. You can ask about its political possibilities on the Politics SE.
4. You can ask about relevant historical events on the History SE.

The result is that you don't make 1 offtopic, opinionated, too broad, and maybe unclear question, somewhere. Rather you ask a lot different questions, on different sites, which is all ontopic and interesting on them.

It is also important to use the SE and the Google simultaneously. You google, think on the results, ask a question on the SE. Read and understand the answers, google for the references, then ask another question on another site. The important thing is, you should be able to do this self-sufficient search-learn-ask cycle.

On this way, you can build your own answer for anything.

Answer (score 6):

It is *very* unlikely that any Stack Exchange site would accept questions like you've suggested.

Stack Exchange generally works best for questions that have (the potential for) a single, objectively correct answer. The questions you're thinking about may have consensus somewhere, but are more likely to result in endless debate.

All that said, Stack Exchange does have chat rooms, and you may be able to engage some of the people from, say, History in such discussions in **chat**, but questions like these will be quickly closed.